# Google Chrome and printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, size

I have a simple div:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:1mm;left:1mm;height:13mm;width:83mm;background-color:rgb(204,221,238) !important;"></div>
```

On screen it render properly and the size is indeed as shown. While printing however the div for some reason changes to width: 89mm. The height increase as well.

In FF this works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how that div fits into the rest of your code, but try setting the DIV to

```
"position: relative"
```